# Массив с дочерними элементами

Tags: laravel, массивы, php

Laravel 5

Есть модель "категории", которая hasMany "Позиции".

Как вывести списком все категории и вложенные в них позиции?

```
$cat = Categoty::all();
$cat_1 = Item::where('cat_id','=',1)->take(2)->get();
$cat_2 = Item::where('cat_id','=',2)->take(2)->get();
$cat_3 = Item::where('cat_id','=',3)->take(2)->get();

return view('admin.dashboard')->with([
        'cat' => $cat,
        'cat_1' => $cat_1,
        'cat_2' => $cat_2,
        'cat_3' => $cat_3,
    ]);
```

Пока что это так выглядит.

Comment: @Commandante, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
$cats = Categoty::all();
foreach($cats as $cat){
  $positions = $cat->positions();
}
```

При том что у вас в моделе Category прописанно

```
public function positions(){
  return $this->hasMany('Position', 'categoty_id');
}
```

А в Position моделе (Если нужно узнать категорию по позиции

```
public function category(){
   return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

Ну и конечно БД должен соответсвовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = Category::with('items')->get();
```

Результатом будет коллекция категорий с вложенными связанными позициями.

Но для этого в моделе `Category` у вас должна быть настроена связь с моделью `Item`.

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Item', 'cat_id');
}
```